# Discord Bot, Discord.js | Get bot to send message after clicking reaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get my first discord bot to send a message after clicking a reaction,

One for yes reaction, one for no

I have my code already send an embed with the reactions

I created a Reaction collector but 
the only thing now its that it instantly reacts with (reacted no) twice, even before I click the reaction

Help is greatly appreciated!

My Code so far:

```
const {Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
const a =
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('boogie time!');
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot)
    {
        if(message.embeds)
        {
            const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg=> msg.title ==='Boogie Time!?');
            if(embedMsg)
            {
                embedMsg.message.react('✅')
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('❌'))

                // This is filter, this specified which reactions it should capture, you can use filter to make sure you're only catching specific reactions by specific user
const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❌') && user.id === message.author.id;

// Here, we're defining a collector that will be active for 30 seconds and collect reactions that pass the above filter
const collector = embedMsg.message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 10000});

// This event is emitted when a reaction passes through the filter
collector.on('collect', r => r.name === '✅' ? 
console.log('Reacted Yes') : console.log('Reacted No'));



            }
        }
        return;
    }


if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'boogie')
{
    const embed = new RichEmbed();
    embed.setTitle("Boogie Time!?")
    embed.setColor("GREEN")
    embed.setDescription("Are you sure?")
    message.channel.send(embed);



};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a several problems here.  The first issue is you are only looking at messages sent by a bot `if(message.author.bot)` and then later trying to filter by that message author which will always be a bot, not you or anyone else `user.id === message.author.id`.  I think your intention may have been to **not** collect bot reactions.

The second issue you have is that the asynchronous execution is causing the collector to get created before the bot adds the initial reaction.

```
embedMsg.message.react('✅')
   .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('❌'))
```

After this call to `.react`, the code below it starts immediate async execution, before the reactions complete.  If you aren't listening to the bots reaction this shouldn't be an issue, but if you enclose the collector creating in a second `.then` statement it will ensure it doesn't create it until the second reaction is complete and you won't need to filter the user.id because the bot shouldn't react after that, thus eliminating both problems.

So the cause of the problem is the bot is collecting it's own two reactions.  Why is it always saying 'React No' then?
This is the third issue:

```
collector.on('collect', r => r.name === '✅' ? 
console.log('Reacted Yes') : console.log('Reacted No'));
```

Here you have forgotten to call out the reactions emoji.  This line should be:

```
collector.on('collect', r => r.emoji.name === '✅' ? 
console.log('Reacted Yes') : console.log('Reacted No'));
```

In conclusion, this should be the changes described above:

```
if(embedMsg)
{
    embedMsg.message.react('✅')
    .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('❌')
        .then(() => {
            // This is filter, this specified which reactions it should capture, you can use filter to make sure you're only catching specific reactions by specific user
            const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❌');

            // Here, we're defining a collector that will be active for 30 seconds and collect reactions that pass the above filter
            const collector = embedMsg.message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 10000});

            // This event is emitted when a reaction passes through the filter
            collector.on('collect', r => r.emoji.name === '✅' ? 
            console.log('Reacted Yes') : console.log('Reacted No'));
    }));
}
```

Comment: This has helped greatly, things are moving smooth there is only one problem left, the bot takes some time to add both reactions so once it adds the X reaction it starts reading too fast and reads the bot adding X and responds (reacted No)

Comment: @AbandonedAccount Check your parenthesis, I noticed one of mine was missing and I fixed it. The second .then statement should be a method on the X reaction, not the check reaction. I've added some indentation to my example that might make it more clear.

Comment: that worked thank you, If I wanted to change the console.log(reacted Yes/No) could I just change it to message.channel.send()? or would I need to create something else??

Comment: changing it to message.channel.send brings it back to the same problem of it reacting to fast to its own reaction, I appreciate it so much with you helping me through this and am sorry there has been so many problems, I've tried hard to do this on my own but just cant seem to get it 100%

Comment: Maybe I could put a delay? but Im not sure any would work the the type of command used?

Comment: I suggest looking for tutorials on Asynchronous programming in Node.js.  It's a tricky subject, not something that can be adequately covered in comments on SO. Specifically in your code you are handling a Promise returned by each reaction.

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/